# problem with unwanted Klipper (or other) keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, clipboard

There seems to be a global shortcut set on my system (Kubuntu) that invokes a list of clipboard history items from which I can "Select to paste". This happens when I press "CTRL + ;" in any window. But I need this shortcut for something else...

I have searched in all the global and custom keyboard shortcut settings, but this does not seem to be set anywhere. Not sure if this is the KDE built-in Klipper Clipboard utility, or something else.

Does anyone recognize the dialog box I am getting, or know how to disable this behavior?

I have already looked into xbindkeys, but no .xbindkeysrc file is created, so I don't think this is the source of the issue...

[image: Photo of dialog box]

Comment: **1**: Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#images for how to add images to your posts or just press `Ctrl+G`. **2**. What version of Kubuntu are you using? An image of the KInfocenter screen would help.

Comment: Do you have foreign keyboards or input methods installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @xiota, I found the "offending" setting:
Input Method Configuration > Addon > Clipboard (Fcitx Clipboard access) > Configure > Trigger key for clipboard history list > click and hit "Esc" to clear the setting.

[screenshot of settings to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMAYh.png)

Comment: thank you so much! I have this exact problem and it was driving me crazy. Never would've suspected it's Fcitx.